# In a Drupal message box, why is the close button not working in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, drupal-6

This is only happening in Chrome. IE and Firefox work just fine. In the console I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`
[image]

It is saying the error is here but I don't even know where this is:

```
(function() {with (this[2]) {with (this[1]) {with (this[0]) {return function(event) {onclose()
};}}}})
```

Comment: do you have that `onclose()` function in your js ?

Comment: Yes, the onclose function exists, there is some javascript that is being inserted on the first line (see the code in the question), but I don't know where it's coming from.

Comment: It is due to conflicts so you'd better use `window.onclose()` instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some sort of conflict with that function name.

Try:

```
window.onclose();
```

Or even better:

```
document.getElementById("aerror").addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('Hello world');
}, false);
```

You should always use event listeners: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#Why_use_addEventListener.3F

Comment: window.onclose() worked. Thanks! I can't award the bounty for another 21 hours, so I will when I can.